# In a WebView is there a way for shouldOverrideUrlLoading to determine if it is catching a redirect vs. a user clicking a link?

Tags: android, webview

I would like to allow redirects to happen naturally in the WebView and only catch a new url if it is a happening because a user clicked something.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem. I needed to open a page in a WebView in my activity. However, when users clicked on a link in the page, I wanted it to be opened in a "new window," meaning the browser activity. This posed a problem if the page has a redirect. In order to accomplish this, I did the following:

1. I only show the webview once the page has finished loading.
2. I keep a boolean telling me when the page had finished loading. User interaction can only happen after a page had finished loading. otherwise it's a redirect and should be opened in my acitivty.

Code sample:

```
private boolean mLoaded = false;

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(mLoaded){ // open in new browser window only if page already finished
        try
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.log(e);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
        layoutHoldingTheWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea per se, but probably useless to the OP.

Answer (score 13):

I just found something in that SDK that might work, [WebView.getHitTestResult()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult%28%29) Let me know if anyone sees any flaws in this method.

Here is an example of how I am using it:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(view.getHitTestResult().getType() > 0){
         // From a user click, handle it yourself.
         return true;
    } else {
         // Nothing clicked, assumed to be a redirect, let it redirect.
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A user clicking on a link with embedded JavaScript seem to return 0 (unknown) which fails this test - at least on Honeycomb anyway.

Comment: Exactly Damian! You're right..doesn't always recognize clicks!

Answer (score 8):

Not directly, no.

You can use a combination of `WebViewClient.onPageStarted` and `WebView.getOriginalUrl` to try to determine if the url being display is the original one requested, but this is *after* the `WebView` has decided to load the Url. This can help determine if a redirect has happened but still *won't* distinguish between user events and script events that do not cause redirects.

If you control the content of the web content, you could also encode the user-clickable Urls in some identifiable way (eg. a proprietary scheme instead of http) and do any additional processing that you require if the criteria match in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

In SDK 24.
can get the result by the new `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`,

there is a method `isRedirect()` in WebResourceRequest  which gets whether the request was a result of a server-side redirect.

Comment: How can do it in android < 24?

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from Garrett's answer because I found it didn't quite work as written , gave a few errors etc. And the part about visibility is in my view not needed. I had the exact same issue as the OP and this is giving the behaviour I want:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        private boolean mLoaded = false;
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(mLoaded){ // open in new browser window only if page already finished
                try
                {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("webview", e.getMessage());
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            mLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do as follow:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
    if (webView.getUrl() != null && webView.getOriginalUrl() != null && webView.getOriginalUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(webView.getUrl()) {
        // Not Redirect
    } else {
        // Redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: A user clicking on a link will appear as a redirect in this code sample.