# how to check if url is redirected or user input in shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: android, android-webview

is there any way to check if a url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading() is redirected or user input in webview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a WebView is there a way for shouldOverrideUrlLoading to determine if it is catching a redirect vs. a user clicking a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852414/in-a-webview-is-there-a-way-for-shouldoverrideurlloading-to-determine-if-it-is-c)